# BsonSerializer Deserialize Script To Wrong BsonDocument

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm using dynamic js queries from browser client to .Net server with mongodb c# driver.

But passing the query to the BsonSerializer result with bad Deserializion.

```
BsonDocument doc = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>("{Policy:{'$gt':5}} ,{Policy:1}");
```

the doc value: {{ "Policy" : { "$gt" : 5 } }}

MongoDB Bug?